# Call to Application_Start after starting application pool in IIS

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, application-start

I would like to know how can I setup the IIS, or the application if needed, for the next requirement:
 - When the application pool starts in IIS it should call to Application_Start in Global.asax

I was playing around with applicationHost.config getting the following code:

```
<applicationPools>
        <add name="mySite" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
        <applicationPoolDefaults>
            <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="false" />
        </applicationPoolDefaults>
    </applicationPools>
```

.
.

```
 <site name="mySite" id="2" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" applicationPool="mySite">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mySite" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="127.0.0.1:8080:" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

So far the Application_Start is called only when a request is done.

Comment: do you mean this: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization

Comment: It looks like something that I need. I will take a look. Thank you!

Comment: @paul What is the equivalent in .net Core ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just want to supplement what @paul said and agree that I was never able to get what Scott Guthrie [said on his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) to fully function. Using:

```
<applicationPools>

    <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />

</applicationPools>
```

would get the Application Pool to preload after recycling (as exemplified by seeing the w3wp.exe process reload on recycling the application pool).

But I never was able to get the second part to work:

```
<sites>

     <site name="MySite" id="1">

          <application path="/" applicationPool="MyAppWorkerProcess" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" />

     </site>

</sites>
```

This may be because when using **serviceAutoStartEnabled** using **serviceAutoStartProvider** is also neccessary and that was just overkill for me since I simply wanted the **Global.asax's Application_Start** to be initialized.

Luckily, after reading [this post](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/terri/implementing-application-initialization-on-iis-7-5/) and installing the [Application Initialization Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) and using this value in the Application configuration instead:

```
<sites>

     <site name="MySite" id="1">

          <application path="/" applicationPool="MyAppWorkerProcess" preloadEnabled="true" />

     </site>

</sites>
```

I was able to see that **Application_Start** is being invoked during initialization. This turns my 10 second initial web service call into a 750 ms initial web service call. Using preloadEnabled is exactly what I needed. I hope it helps others as well.

Comment: I came here looking for a way to do this with Hangfire to keep it running and ended up finding [this](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/best-way-to-ensure-that-hangfire-is-always-running/133/3) forum post where odinserj explains the difference between the two methods very well.

Comment: What is the equivalent in .net Core ?